# Geometric interpretation of Theta functions and the Jacobi inversion problem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, riemann-surfaces, theta-functions

A great part of complex geometry and, algebraic geometry has been developed to address the theory of abelian integrals/functions. A very special problem that kept many great mathematicians busy was Jacobi inversion problem.

I have a modest notion of how this problem can be approached through the lens of complex algebraic geometry. However, the work of Jacobi on elliptic and more generally, on hyperelliptic functions, precedes the works of Riemann, Weierstrass, and the modern school on several complex variables. It seems that the main ingredient for Jacobi were his "theta functions".

**I encountered theta functions a few times, especially when working with classical modular forms and the algebrization of complex tori. In both cases, they seemed quite mysterious to me and I'd love to understand how these "apparently unmotivated" objects can be interpreted through the lens of complex algebraic geometry. I would also appreciate if you can explain to me, from the geometric perspective, how theta functions provide a common framework to discuss "apparently different" problems like: the Jacobi inversion problem, classical modular forms and, the algebrization of complex tori.**

In the next paragraphs, I will explain how I see those things from the geometric point of view, so you might have an idea of my background. Please feel free to correct me if I say something wrong. I would also be grateful if you can give me precise references for my intuitions.

Given an irreducible polynomial $P \in  \mathbb{C}[T_1, T_2]$, a rational function $R \in  \mathbb{C}(T_1, T_2)$ and a complex number $z_0$, we have an associated abelian integral $A(z) = \int_{z_0}^z R(x,y(x))dz$. Formally, $x \mapsto y(x)$ is the "multi-valued algebraic function" defined by the implicit equation $P(x,y) = 0$ for $(x,y) \in  \mathbb{C}^2$.

The modern geometric point of view interprets abelian integrals as a meromorphic 1-form $\omega_P$ on the compact Riemann surface $X_P$ associated to the affine plane complex curve $C_P = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[T_1,T_2]/(P)$. There are several equivalent constructions of $X_P$, but shortly saying $X_P$ is canonically isomorphic to the analytification of the normalization of the projective closure $\overline{C_P} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^2$. Moreover, the genus $g$ of $X_P$ can be calculated using the degree of $\overline{C_P}$ and the data of its singularities.

Things are particularly nice when $\omega_P$ is a holomorphic 1-form. In this case $\omega_P$ can be integrated against paths in $X_P$ yielding values in $\mathbb{C}$. Given two points $x_0$ and $x_f$ in $X_P$ and two paths $\gamma$,$\gamma'$ from $x_0$ to $x_f$, then $\int_\gamma \omega_P = \int_\gamma' \omega_P \iff [\gamma'^{-1} \circ \gamma] = 0 \in H_1(X_P , \mathbb{Z})$.  Thus an "inverse" of the abelian integral $A$ should have $2g$ periods.

When $g = 1$, we get the classic theory of double-periodic (meromorphic) functions in $\mathbb{C}$, which can be studied through the classical Weierstrass $\wp$-function (and its derivative). When $g \geq 2$, we have no other choice but to use the Abel-Jacobi map as a bridge that allows us to interpret the "inverse of $A$" as a meromorphic function of the Jacobian torus $J(X_P)$. The latter is complex torus of $\mathbb{C}$-dimension $g$, which comes with a natural ample line bundle (according to  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1088031/897326 ), hence $J(X_P)$ is algebraic (which was already obvious in the case $g$=1).

With respect to classical modular forms, I don't see very clearly their relation with the Jacobi inversion problem. In the particular example of $P(T_1,T_2) = T_2^2 - (T_1^3 - aT_1 - b)$ with $4a +27b^2 \neq 0$, the constants $a,b$ correspond to the Eisenstein series of a certain lattice $\Lambda$. The inverting $\omega_P$ yields the Weierstrass $\wp$-function of $\Lambda_P$, which can be used to give an explicit isomorphism between $X_P$ and its Jacobian torus $J(X_P) \cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_P$. In general, I like the moduli interpretation of modular forms, so I suspect that classical modular forms appear in this context because different elliptic functions might be related to tori with different complex structures.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for how to use the $\theta$-function to solve the Jacobian inversion problem?